# Python CSV Module - Can't hold text format

Tags: python, csv, formatting

EDIT*
Solution was to wrap text in the column.  This will restore the original format.

I am trying to create a CSV using the CSV module provided in Python.  My issue is when the CSV is created the contents of the file inserted into the field loses it's format.

Example input can be pulled from 'whois 8.8.8.8'.  I want the field to hold the formatting from that input.

Is there a way to maintain the files original format within the cell?

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
import csv

file1 = sys.argv[1]
file2 = sys.argv[2]

myfile1 = open(file1, "rb")
myfile2 = open(file2, "rb")
ofile  = open('information.csv', "wb")

stuffwriter = csv.writer(ofile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

stuffwriter.writerow([myfile1.read(),myfile2.read()])

myfile1.close()
myfile2.close()
ofile.close()
```

Example Input(All In One Cell):

```
#
# ARIN WHOIS data and services are subject to the Terms of Use
# available at: https://www.arin.net/whois_tou.html
#


#
# Query terms are ambiguous.  The query is assumed to be:
#     "n 8.8.8.8"
#
# Use "?" to get help.
#

#
# The following results may also be obtained via:
# http://whois.arin.net/rest/nets;q=8.8.8.8?showDetails=true&showARIN=false&ext=netref2
#

Level 3 Communications, Inc. LVLT-ORG-8-8 (NET-8-0-0-0-1) 8.0.0.0 - 8.255.255.255
Google Incorporated LVLT-GOOGL-1-8-8-8 (NET-8-8-8-0-1) 8.8.8.0 - 8.8.8.255



#
# ARIN WHOIS data and services are subject to the Terms of Use
# available at: https://www.arin.net/whois_tou.html
#
```

Would like the cell to hold the format above.  Currently when I open in Excel it is all one line.

I am getting my data from executing:

```
whois 8.8.8.8 > inputData.txt
echo "8.8.8.8 - Google" > inputData2.txt
python CreateCSV inputData2.txt inputData.txt
```

This is what I would like to see:
http://www.2shared.com/photo/WZwDC7w2/Screen_Shot_2013-06-06_at_1231.html

This is what I'm seeing:
http://www.2shared.com/photo/9dRFGCxh/Screen_Shot_2013-06-06_at_1222.html

Comment: can you give an example of the formats? I am not exactly sure what is going wrong from your description.

Comment: This is some
Stuff that should
Be in one cell

Not sure if the above kept it's format, but every capital letter should be the beginning of a new line.  I want to maintain that new line within the cell.  When it is put into the cell with the above python script, it all becomes a single line within the cell.

Comment: Welcome to SO, I do not mean this in a crude way, but being specific is generally pretty helpful and "some stuff" does not really tell me what it is like. Please explain what you mean by 'some field to hold the formatting' and what is going on that not what you want to happen

Comment: Apologize for not being specific enough, just didn't want to overwhelm the post.  I edited above to provide whois for 8.8.8.8.  I would like to keep that format when I open it in Excel.

Comment: Okay, just to clear a couple more things up...the lines beginning in `#`, are those comments or do those go in the csv? And with the google parts, what are those supposed to be like in the csv, one cell each, or 7 (using `split`)?

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you'd like output in CSV format from the given example input?

Comment: The # are naturally provided from running the command line 'whois' (8.8.8.8 is a Google DNS) and should be (but don't have to be if that's what's causing the issue) included in the cell along with every line maintaining that readable format/spacing.  When I open the CSV in Excel as is, all of that input is on one line making it complicated to read.

Comment: Provided two links in my post, one to what I'm seeing and one to what I would like to see.  I don't have the rep here to upload pictures :\

Comment: Just use a loop and `readline` to continually write the next line into the csv

Comment: You can continuously write the lines into the same cell?

Comment: Appears the format is held in the .csv.  Best option to get format back is to convert to .xlsx and just opening (double click) the cell to bring it back.

Answer (score 0):

1. Convert .CSV to an .XLSX
2. In Excel, right click column with data that lost it's format
3. Select 'Format Cells...'
4. Select the 'Alignment' tab
5. Check 'Wrap Text'
6. All is good!